# Multiple Android Supprt files in Project and libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I'll try to explain as much as possible as this is more of a structural problem than code problem, ok, so i have project in which i am using android-support-library-v4, now in the same project i have now added three new libraries, these libraries also include android-support-library-v4, as they are part of their own code framework,

Now the problem is this is causing a jar mismatch in my project because i now have three same android-support-library-v4 in my project.

I tried the solution of removing the android-support-library-v4 jar file from my main project but this does not resolve the jar mismatch from the other libraries i have used in the project, and i cannot delete the android-support-library-v4 jars from the libraries as they would not work without them meaning they will stop functioning...

Comment: first delete all android-support-library-v4 library then add same android-support-library-v4 libarary to all project

Comment: Common jar are always place on top most library project and try to extends those library to ur main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution for this problem , What i usually do is , steps are.

1. Just copy any **android-support-library-v4** from any lib project
2. Then **copy and replace** this to all other libs projects.
3. This will remove your mismatch problem

> I will suggest you to use Android Studio as Google official IDE.